# contentful is not imported into next 13 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

```
import {createClient} from "contentful";

const client = createClient({
  space: "*",
  accesToken: "*",
});

export default client;
```

#### **ERROR**: Module '"contentful"' has no exported member 'createClient'. Did you mean to use 'import createClient from "contentful"' instead?

---

Comment: This should work [according to the docs](https://contentful.github.io/contentful.js/contentful/4.2.1/#using-es6-import), however, try this instead `import * as contentful from 'contentful'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.